# Change the curvature of line() in R

Tags: r

I'm using `library(geosphere)` and I am plotting lines between close points. Is there a way to make the lines curvature more prominent?

[image: Pic]

I'd like to have bent curves between the points.

My code looks something like this:

```
 lat_ca <- 39.164141
 lon_ca <- -121.640625
 lat_me <- 45.213004
 lon_me <- -68.906250
 inter <- gcIntermediate(c(lon_ca, lat_ca), c(lon_me, lat_me), n=50, addStartEnd=TRUE)
 lines(inter)
```

Comment: Running your code shows a lot of curvature on my plot. If your points are close together, remember there will be little/no curvature.

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked the question. Since as far as I understood the `gcIntermediate` function will return the points following the curvature of the Earth.

Comment: So you want more curvature than the great circle path?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want :)

Comment: Inspiration?http://m.jeb.biologists.org/content/209/1/128